# iOS scroll view childs are not getting touched

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm new to iOS so I'm getting problem with scroll view.
My scroll view having image views as subviews. Whenever I'm trying to touch image inside scroll view, scroll view touch is getting enable instead of subview.
How to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: try `scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Tap gesture recognizer to the scroll view for enabling touch inside scroll view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singlTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(methodName:)];
singlTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollViewName addGestureRecognizer:singlTap];
```

then write your code in specified method.

```
-(void)methodName:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
     //your code here
}
```

Thats all